# Listview column width settings inline

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am trying to set the column widths of a listview.

I have reviewed tons of links and not one I have found describes setting column width of a listview inline. WITHOUT a CSS file. Scowered the MSDN on line doc which says to use either CSS or inline, but I can't seem to get the inline working. Even the example shows fixed col widths....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx#ApplyingStylesToListViewItems

I have added Width property to labels in the itemTemplate and Alternate template, tried settings in LayoutTemplate.

Nothing seems to work. Can someone point me to a tutorial or provide a sample of coding to adjust column width for the Listview WEB Control, not Windows listview control.

THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was defined another table in my template. So, lets say I only wanted to change the size of the EditItemTemplate fields and my LayoutTemplate has 9 s.
In the EditItemTemplate I did:

```
        <EditItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9">
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <!-- any controls you want... -->
              <asp:TextBox ID="blah" runat="server" Text="'<%# Bind("blah") %>'                                          Width="whateverpx"/>
```

... close tags...
The idea is to make your template layout however you want and set widths on your asp: controls.